# There is an error in XML document

Tags: c#, xmlserializer, xml-deserialization

I am getting the following exception when I am trying to deserialize the xml document. Xml document has a tag as url in which google search link may present. Google search link contains '=' which is not accepted in the xml document while deserializing it. I am getting the xml from server. So I cannot do anything with the string that is present in the url tag. I have to do something on my client part. How can I overcome this problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
 <status>
  <code>000</code>
  <message>Successfully completed</message>
 </status>
 <reports>
   <report>
      <id>9973</id>
      <url>http://www.google.com/search?q=guns&client=safari&safe=active</url>
   </report>
 </reports>
</response>
```

Exception :

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll but was not handled in user code

Innerexception:

> {"'=' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'. Line 136, position 53."}

Comment: How are we going to reproduce this issue?

Comment: "I am getting the xml from server." What server? It sounds like it's simply invalid XML, and whoever is supplying it should fix it.

Comment: you probably need HttpUtility.UrlEncode Method

Comment: @JonSkeet I have updated my question with the xml that I am getting.

Comment: @PatrickHofman i have updated the question for your reference

Comment: And yes, that's invalid XML. The `&` should be escaped to `&amp;`. Whatever is generating the XML is broken. That's all we can say at the moment.

Comment: Indeed. Check an online XML validator and you will see it is invalid.

Comment: @NahumLitvin I could only pass the xml to the deserialization function. It is not accepting the xml and throws exception

Comment: @JonSkeet It was escaped. I am doing the following string manipulation before passing it to deserialization function.  mResponse.Replace("&amp;", "&").Replace("&lt;", "<").Replace("&gt;", ">").Replace("&quot;", "\"").Replace("&apos;", "'");  problem is with "=".

Comment: @Fresher: Well don't do that! (And how were we meant to know that you were doing that?) You've converted valid XML into non-XML. That's clearly not going to be a good idea when what you're passing the result to expects XML.

Comment: (And no, the problem isn't the `=` - the problem is that the XML deserializer is expecting `&` to be followed by an entity name, which `=` can't be part of. So it's `&` that's really causing the problem... it's only that it gets *noticed* at `=`.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks. Now I know what the actual problem is. But I need to convert &amp; to & so that I could convert &amp;lt; to &lt; and then to <. I will have to do some extra manipulations with the xml string. I will do it. Thank you so much for clarifying the problem.

Comment: @Fresher: No, you don't. You shouldn't need to "unescape" the XML at all. Performing string operations on XML like this is a *really bad idea* in almost all cases, and you haven't given any indication of why you'd want to do so at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet  Actually I am getting the required xml as a string in another xml. so I need to unescape the xml after parsing it out from string tag. While unescaping I also changed &amp; to & which I should not have done. now I removed it as per your advice. everything works fine. thanks.

Comment: None of this is clear at all - and *all* this information should have been part of the original question. The chances of manual string replacement being a good idea are miniscule though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML is invalid. The URL is breaking the XML standard. Specifically you should escape the `&`: `&amp;`.

This is the valid XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
 <status>
  <code>000</code>
  <message>Successfully completed</message>
 </status>
 <reports>
   <report>
      <id>9973</id>
      <url>http://www.google.com/search?q=guns&amp;client=safari&amp;safe=active</url>
   </report>
 </reports>
</response>
```

Check your XML export function to make sure it escapes the URL properly.